# How to parse a String that contains many ints

Tags: java, xml, string, parsing, int

I'm trying to read some int from a xml document:

```
<aaa>
    <agent>
       <name>Agent 1</name>
       <position>4 5</position>
       <vector>87 78 54 5 -4</vector>
    </agent>
</aaa>
```

That's my Java code:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory documentFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

DocumentBuilder builder = documentFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document document = builder.parse(new File("utility.xml"));

NodeList agents = document.getElementsByTagName("agent");

for(int i=0; i<agents.getLength(); i++) {
        Node node = agents.item(i);

        if(node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                Element agente = (Element)node;

                String name = agente.getElementsByTagName("name").item(0).getFirstChild().getNodeValue();
                String position = agente.getElementsByTagName("position").item(0).getFirstChild().getNodeValue();
                String vector = agente.getElementsByTagName("vector").item(0).getFirstChild().getNodeValue();
```

I want to parse the string position into 2 Integer (4 and 5), and I want to parse the string vector into 5 Integer (and put them into an array).
How can I do it? Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

You may use a `Scanner` and read the contents of the `String` by using `nextInt`:

```
String stringRead = ...; //imagine you read <position> here
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(stringRead);
List<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<>();
while (scanner.hasNext()) {
    intList.add(scanner.nextInt());
}
```

If you use Java 8, then you can make it shorter by using the power of streams:

```
String stringRead = ...; //imagine you read <position> here
List<Integer> intList = Arrays.stream(stringRead.split("\\s+"))
    .map(x -> Integer.valueOf(x))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

The logic of converting to int[]

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    String position ="87 78 54 5 -4";
    String vector = "4 5";

    String[] posArr = position.split(" ");
    int[] positionArray = new int[posArr.length];

    for(int i = 0 ; i < posArr.length ; i ++) {
        positionArray[i] = Integer.parseInt(posArr[i]);
    }

    String[] vectArr = vector.split(" ");
    int[] vectorArray = new int[vectArr.length];
    for(int i = 0 ; i < vectArr.length ; i ++) {
        vectorArray[i] = Integer.parseInt(vectArr[i]);
    }
}
```